# Get current directory, not path, in a function .bashrc

Tags: bash, rvm

I would like to display a * in my prompt if the name of the current rvm gemset does not match the name of the current directory. I can get the name of the current gemset with no problem by using `$(~/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt g)` which, if the gemset is foo, will return `@foo`.

I've tried both `"@${PWD##*/}"` and `"@${\W}"` but unfortunately with no success. My entire function looks like this:

```
function ps1_rvm() {
  [[ $(~/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt g) != "@${PWD##*/}" ]] && echo "*"
}
```

I am then using this function to set the value of PS1 so that it is output to my prompt.

Edit: I want to get the directory name, not the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
function ps1_rvm() {
  [[ $(~/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt g) != $(basename $(pwd)) ]] && echo "*"
}
```

? That should work...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this returns the directory path, not the directory name.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not reading your question entirely. I updated the answer, please try again.
Also I fixed the pwD typo.